# lxml::etree::_ElementStringResult.getparent() works incorrectly

Tags: python, lxml

I did not find anyone explaining this error...

I'm using lxml 3.1.0.

When there is an HTML/XML like that:

`<h1 class="fn"><strong class="brand">Lange</strong> XT 100 LV Ski Boots 2014</h1>`

the _ElementStringResult of string " XT 100 LV Ski Boots 2014" will be returned when we run:

```
>> elemstr = tree.xpath('//body//h1/text()')[0]
```

However, when we run as follows, we would get...

```
>> parent = elemstr.getparent()
>> tree.getpath(parent)
/html/body/therestofthepath/h1/strong
```

Did anyone have a problem like that? Is there any other way that manual check if the text is the same, and otherwise checking with the text child of the parent?

Comment: nothing ever works incorrectly :)

Comment: if you explain me why it's correct, I'll be glad to agree with you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct behaviour for element-tree (ET). The reason stems from the way ET represents text nodes: Only a text-node which is the **first** of the children of an element is represented by the attribute *text*.

Other intermingled text-nodes are the *tail* of their preceding sibling, in this case the strong-element.

```
import lxml.etree

xml = """<h1 class="fn"><strong class="brand">Lange</strong> XT 100 LV Ski Boots 2014</h1>"""

tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
elemstr = tree.xpath('//h1/text()')[0]
print elemstr.getparent().tail
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for! however, a bit of a shame that it works like that... :)

Comment: Yes, I've been struggling with this from time to time myself. It makes some things much easier, but sometimes it bytes.