# How to find text's Parent Node?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

If I use:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = request.get(url='someurl')
tree = html.document_fromstring(response.text)


all_text = tree.xpath('//text()')     # which give all text from page
```

Inside this all_text list we have all the text from page. Now I want to know if:

```
text_searched = all_text[all_text.index('any string which is in all_text list')]
```

Is it possible to get to the web element of the text been searched?

Comment: I think BeatuifulSoup is a better option for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`getparent()`** method for this purpose, for example :

```
.....
.....
all_text = tree.xpath('//text()')

first_text = all_text[0]
parent_element = first_text.getparent()

print html.tostring(parent_element)
```

---

Note that the behavior of `getparent()` [might not be the one you expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570796/lxmletree-elementstringresult-getparent-works-incorrectly) in case current text element located after element node in the same parent element. Due to the tree model implemented by `lxml`, the text is considered `tail` of the preceding element instead of `child` of the containing element in this case, so `getparent()` will return the preceding element. See example below to get a clear idea of what I've been talking about :

```
from lxml import html
raw = '''<div>
    <span>foo</span>
    bar
</div>'''
root = html.fromstring(raw)
texts = root.xpath('//text()[normalize-space()]')
print [t for t in texts]
# output : ['foo', '\n\tbar\n']

[html.tostring(e.getparent()) for e in texts]
# output : ['<span>foo</span>\n\tbar\n', '<span>foo</span>\n\tbar\n']
# see that calling getparent() on 'bar' returns the <span> not the <div>
```

Comment: Hi, the solution worked. Really thanks for your help.