# Remove elements from tree based on list of terms

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to capture some text from a webpage (whose URL is passed when running the script), but its buried in a paragraph tag with no other attributes assigned.  I can collect the contents of every paragraph tag, but I want to remove any elements from the tree that contain any of a list of keywords.

I get the following error:

> tree.remove(elem)  TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type
>   (expected lxml.etree._Element, got _ElementStringResult)

I understand that what I am getting back when I try to iterate through the tree is the wrong type, but how do I get the element instead?

Sample Code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    from lxml import html
    from lxml import etree

    url = sys.argv[1]
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    terms = ['keyword1','keyword2','keyword3','keyword4','keyword5','keyword6','keyword7']
    paragraphs = tree.xpath('//p/text()')
    for elem in paragraphs:
        if any(term in elem for term in terms):
            tree.remove(elem)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find text's Parent Node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520709/how-to-find-texts-parent-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `elem` is an [`_ElementStringResult`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementStringResult-class.html) which has the instance method `getparent`. Its parent is an `Element` object of one of the `<p>` nodes.

The parent has a `remove` method which can be used to remove it from the tree:

```
element.getparent().remove(element)
```

I do not believe there is a more direct way and I don't have a good answer to why there isn't a `removeself` method.

Using the example html:

```
content = '''
<root>
    <p> nothing1 </p>
    <p> keyword1 </p>
    <p> nothing2 </p>
    <p> nothing3 </p>
    <p> keyword4 </p>
</root>
'''
```

You can see this in action in your code with:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree

tree = html.fromstring(content)

terms = ['keyword1','keyword2','keyword3','keyword4','keyword5','keyword6','keyword7']
paragraphs = tree.xpath('//p/text()')
for elem in paragraphs:
    if any(term in elem for term in terms):
        actual_element = elem.getparent() 
        actual_element.getparent().remove(actual_element)

for child in tree.getchildren():
    print('<{tag}>{text}</{tag}>'.format(tag=child.tag, text=child.text))

# Output:
# <p> nothing1 </p>
# <p> nothing2 </p>
# <p> nothing3 </p>
```

From the comments, it seems like this code isn't working for you. If so, you might need to provide more information about the structure of your html.

Comment: I can't get the parent of _ElementStringResult, because getparent() expects an _Element.

Comment: @user2912466 Did you try it? http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementStringResult-class.html

Comment: I did, but the solution poses two problems:

First, it complains Element isn't the child of the node, because the parents of each of the paragraph tags in the tree is "<Element p at 0x103aac940>", but it only catches the first word.

Secondly, this example only would work if there were one paragraph tag, but I am capturing all of them, and then removing specific ones.  In this example, body works because there is one body, so when you remove that element, nothing else would go.  But if I `p.getparent().remove(p)`, it would remove all the paragraph elements.  How would I get around that?

Comment: @user2912466 It wouldn't remove all the elements, it would remove only `p`.

Comment: @user2912466 Check out the updated answer, I guess you need to call `getparent` twice; the first time to get the `<p>` node, and the second time to get its parent.

Comment: So looking at that, and seeing a diagram of the structure of the object, the answer makes perfect sense.  It runs without complaint, but none of the elements with the keywords present are removed from `paragraphs`. Now that I understand your answer, I doubly don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: @user2912466 I'm having an issue installing lxml on this machine, but it might be a good idea idea to break down your code and add a bunch of `print` statements to see if things are going "as expected" throughout the function. For example, I wouldn't be surprised if the expression `term in elem for term in terms` is behaving oddly. If each `elem` is a `_ElementStringResult`, then what does `term in elem` mean? It might not act the same way as it would for a string.

Comment: @user2912466 I updated my answer with example html and using your code. It's working for me.

Comment: I ran your code, and I see we have a misunderstanding.  I'm not trying to remove the elements from `tree`, I'm trying to remove them from the list in '`paragraphs`. I'm sorry if I've been unclear.  I want `paragraphs` to have all the `<p>`tags from the html except the ones with keywords in them.