# Trying to iterate over text() nodes to find their parents

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xpath, lxml

Suppose I have the following example XML

```
<a>some <b>text</b> example</a>
```

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) let me query for the text nodes in a few different ways:

```
>>> xml.xpath("//text()")
['some ', 'text', ' example']
>>> xml.xpath("//a/text()")
['some ', ' example']
>>> xml.xpath("//b/text()")
['text']
```

So far, so good (these are all pretty-printed [`lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult-class.html) objects). But now I’d like to get to the parent nodes of these text nodes:

```
>>> xml.xpath("//text()/parent::*")
[<Element a at 0x10aa383c0>, <Element b at 0x10aa38410>]
>>> xml.xpath("//a/text()/parent::*")
[<Element a at 0x10aa383c0>]
>>> xml.xpath("//b/text()/parent::*")
[<Element b at 0x10aa38410>]
>>> xml.xpath("//*/text()/parent::*")
[<Element a at 0x10aa383c0>, <Element b at 0x10aa38410>]
```

As typical XPath operations these work, and I get result sets of parent nodes back. But I’d like to iterate over the text nodes and *then* get their respective parents:

```
>>> for e in xml.xpath("//text()"):
...     print(e.xpath("./parent::*"))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

Hm, ok, that seems to be an implementation detail of lxml or even the underlying [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)? But [`getparent()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html) to the rescue… or?

```
>>> for e in xml.xpath("//text()"):
...     print(f"'{e}'", e.getparent())
... 
'some ' <Element a at 0x10aa383c0>
'text' <Element b at 0x10aa38410>
' example' <Element b at 0x10aa38410>
```

And this is what puzzles me: while above, during top-down search the parent nodes made sense for all text nodes, going bottom-up they are different: the `' example'` text node has parent `a` or `b`, depending on how I query for its parent.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug (perhaps owing to the [`.text` and `.tail` of element nodes](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text)?

**Addendum**

After looking at the [relevant lxml source code](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/3c99b116c075c4e93de274ada138eb69a715da59/src/lxml/extensions.pxi#L722-L780) I think that the internal [`_elementStringResultFactory`](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/3c99b116c075c4e93de274ada138eb69a715da59/src/lxml/extensions.pxi#L747) would need to be fixed; see bug [1859435](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1859435). Meanwhile, the following workaround gives me the expected results:

```
>>> for e in xml.xpath("//text()"):
...     p = e.getparent()
...     print(f"'{e}'", p.getparent() if e.is_tail else p)
... 
'some ' <Element a at 0x110799460>
'text' <Element b at 0x1100ad230>
' example' <Element a at 0x110799460>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lxml::etree::\_ElementStringResult.getparent() works incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570796/lxmletree-elementstringresult-getparent-works-incorrectly)

Comment: @Markus, thank you. The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570796/lxmletree-elementstringresult-getparent-works-incorrectly#24570953) supports my suspicion that the behavior is lxml/implementation specific. But what is the correct XML behavior? I had expected that ' example'’s parent is a and not b…  Also, I’ve just now added an addendum with a workaround and source reference.

Comment: The concept of a parent in XML itself is only defined between elements, so a text node has no parent. But XPath/XQuery extend this concept to nodes. The underlying data model is defined in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#TextNode. Its not an easy read but I think it effectively boils down to the intuitive interpretation that the enclosing element is the parent node of a text node.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Stefan’s comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1859435/comments/2) on the [lxml bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1859435) (marked as “Won’t fix” now):

> I consider this a feature. […]
>
> Maybe "parent" isn't the ideal word. Maybe there could be better documentation, or an additional example in the docs somewhere. Doc PR welcome, but I don't think the behaviour should change.

So, while this particular lxml behavior deviates from standard XML (see [Markus’ comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876655/trying-to-iterate-over-text-nodes-to-find-their-parents#comment105920128_59876655)) it is intended. The code I used in above’s **Addendum** is, I guess, the proper way of accessing the parent node of text nodes (i.e. checking whether they’re `tail` or not):

```
>>> for e in xml.xpath("//text()"):
...     p = e.getparent()
...     print(f"'{e}'", p.getparent() if e.is_tail else p)
```

Comment: +1 Very interesting find! I would also say that this is a deviation from XML+XPath standards. Elements cannot be parents of text nodes that are their siblings. This behaviour of lxml is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I created the *xml* object as follows:

```
txt = '<a>some <b>text</b> example</a>'
xml = etree.fromstring(txt)
```

To print all text nodes and their parents (tag names), proceed as follows:

1. Define a function getting the list of parents of the given *node*:

   ```
   def getParents(node):
       rv = []
       if node.is_tail:
           node = node.getparent()
       while True:
           node = node.getparent()
           if node is None:
               return rv
           rv.append(node.tag)
   ```
2. Print the result (content of each text node and its patents), running:

   ```
   for node in xml.xpath("//text()"):
       print(node, getParents(node))
   ```

For your XML sample I got:

```
some  ['a']
text ['b', 'a']
 example ['a']
```

Comment: Yup, thanks! This is quite similar to the code I used in my **Addendum** above. A thought and _without_ actually trying the code: I think you could replace the while loop with `rv.extend(node.xpath("ancestor::*"))` (might want to reverse the ancestor list).